# Convert XSD Regex into Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, xsd

I want to convert the below XSD regular expression into equivalent Java regex

XSD Regex is `([\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{Z}\p{P}]){1,255}`

Would you please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Double up the backslashes to embed the regex in a Java string

```
String regexStr = "([\\p{L}\\p{Nd}\\p{Z}\\p{P}]){1,255}";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(regexStr);
```